# Send keys to element selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am writing a script to automatically fill out a form for me, but I am struggling to 'find element'. I can see it when I inspect, but I cant get it to send information to the placeholder.

This is the element im trying to send_keys to.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Next step" class="pl-10 pr-12 form-input block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5" required="" value="">
```

This is the parent element.

```
<div class="nested-fields air-pipeline-step-item" draggable="true" data-handler-id="T0" style="opacity: 1;"><input name="vacancy[vacancy_pipeline_steps_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value=""><input name="vacancy[vacancy_pipeline_steps_attributes][0][step_order]" type="hidden" value="0"><input name="vacancy[vacancy_pipeline_steps_attributes][0][display_name]" type="hidden" value="Awaiting Review">
```

When trying:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_name('vacancy[vacancy_pipeline_steps_attributes][0][id]').click()
```

I get:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

I would like to click on this element and then give it a value. Any suggestions on how to do this ?

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Can you share any type of error you are getting? You should be able to fill out a text box using the elements name like: `driver.find_element_by_name("ElementName").send_keys("TextToSend")`. That uses element name to find the element, but you can use other methods.

Comment: I cannot unfortunately, but I can give me information around that element if that helps ? @Prophet

Comment: The problem is that Im not sure what to 'find_element_by'. There is no name, id, link_text to find_by. @JasonCook

Comment: Maybe giving parent elements will help. The element itself attributes doesn't look like unique values.

Comment: @Prophet I have updated the question :) let me know if that helps

Comment: I see. It helps to say that this is not enough... I'm sorry.. Can you at least post a big HTML block including this element, not just the nearest parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a css selector here – allows for more versatile element selection:

```py
css_selector = 'div[class*="nested-fields"][class*="air-pipeline-step-item"] > input[type="text"]'

# Easier to navigate try and excepts with find many
my_input = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(css_selector)
if my_input:
    my_input = my_input[0]
else:
   # Try a diff selector – or raise an error
   raise ValueError(f'couldn\'t find an element with using {css_selector=}')

# Continue code here 
my_input.send_keys('Hello World!')
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? @andrew-reiblein

Answer (score 0):

you can use find_element_by_class_name() method to find the element and the send the keys. So the code will look like this.

```
// driver should be initialized before
field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("class_name")
field.sendKeys("key")
```